# How do I select Document Label values through the API?

Tags: docusignapi

I have Document Labels set up for my account with lists of optional values.  How do I select the value for each label when I am using the API to create and send envelopes with documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [lisEnvelopeCustomFields](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeCustomFields/list/) api to retrieve the [Document Labels](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-document-labels) of an envelope

Please note that the DocuSign web UI refers as Document Labels. However API refers to them as Custom Fields.

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you so much! It was the difference in the naming conventions that was throwing me off.